# Any method to get the stack size of all functions in a file or a project in C language?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, stack-size

I want to get all functions whose stack size is bigger than the assigned size, is there any easy method to suggest?

Get the .obj file, disassemble it, and then analyze the output file?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: IME, if the stack size is bigger than the default size, the compiler will usually complain and not compile the code.

Comment: What is the "stack size" of a function? The amount of additional space the function may use on the stack when called? Do you include calls the function makes in this calculation, and if so does this make the stack size of a recursive function infinite?

Comment: to detect the risk of stack overflow. i want to get the functions who has too big stack, and refacor them

Comment: Do you have access to the source, or do you have to analyze the object files?

Comment: recursive fucntion is not in consider.

Comment: @Rudy that is definitely not true in general (osx gcc is an example)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the assembly dump for each function.  In gcc, you use the `-S` option.

Let's say you are interested in the function `foo`.  Then, gcc mangles the function name to `_foo`.  If you take a peek at the assembly, you should see, near the top of the function, an instruction to move the stack pointer.  For example, in OSX you have something like:

```
_foo:
    ...
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    ...
    subq $48, %rsp
```

That number, `$48`, is the stack size.

Alternatively, you can look for the equivalent command using `nm` to find the address where the function starts, `ndisasm` to give you a human readable dump, and then scanning for the where the stack pointer is moved.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of embedded computing, infinite recursion is much more likely culprit in stack overflow than any particular call.

That being said, in the first approximation, look for locally-allocated arrays:

```
void foo() {
    ...
    char buffer[1024] = "";
    ...
}
```

Also, don't forget `alloca()` call - it dynamically allocates space on the stack the same way `malloc()` allocates it on the heap.